# If my bluetooth device has both base rate(for audio streaming) and ble(for control), how can I use pygatt to connect to each of them?

Tags: python, windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am still learning bluetooth and now I am faced with a problem: my company's product has both base rate (for audio streaming) and ble (for sending/receiving commands). When I use pygatt's `adapter.connect('MAC ADDRESS')` to establish a connection with the product, how can I know which one (base or ble) I am connecting with?

By the way, I am using gatttool on Linux. I can find the UUID used for SPP (according to product specification) thanks to the command `primary`, but I cannot find any command in pygatt that has the same function as `primary`. Any suggestion would be appreciated!